# website made from replit is not displaying text properly

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-website, replit

I am having some problems making the website mobile friendly. the text starts coming up all weird and not in alignment at all. Any suggestions as to what I can add to make the text normal again.
website coded in html, js, python

[On pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HAGP.png)

[On phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNm1Y.png)

This is happening in some other webpages too

The code block regarding this:

```
<br>
    {%block content%}
    {%include 'navbar.html'%}
    {%endblock%}
    <br><br>
    <center>
        <div class="formdiv">
    <form method="POST" action="{{url_for('test_results')}}">
        <h1>A test to help you explore careers</h1>

        <br><br><br>
        <h2>Are you ...?</h2>
        <ul class="checkbox-grid">
        {%for i in are_you%}
        {%for j in are_you[i]%}
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="{{i}}"><label for="{{i}}">{{j}}</label></li>
        {%endfor%}
        {%endfor%}
        </ul>

        
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <h2>Can you ...?</h2>
        <ul class="checkbox-grid">
        {%for i in can_you%}
        {%for j in can_you[i]%}
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="{{i}}"><label for="{{i}}">
```

Comment: You are using too much <br> tags to seperate content! Try to organize them into divs and use css to align them properly. Use flex property on divs if needed to align them. You can google about them. Also look into https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 2):

Your website is not responsive. If you don't want to make the code responsive by yourself, you can use CSS libraries like bootstrap to do the heavy work for you.